# How to insert element into HTML structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt

After compilation GWT client side from my widgets I'm getting the following structure.

```
<td align="left" width="100%" class="gwt-TabBarRest-wrapper" style="vertical-align: bottom;"><div class="gwt-TabBarRest" style="white-space: normal; height: 100%;">&nbsp;</div></td>
```

How can I put button element instead of `&nbsp;` to have this structure:

```
<td align="left" width="100%" class="gwt-TabBarRest-wrapper" style="vertical-align: bottom;"><div class="gwt-TabBarRest" style="white-space: normal; height: 100%;"><button type="button" class="gwt-Button helpButton"></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all set an `Id` for your `div`.

Your html now looks like something like this

```html
<td align="left" width="100%" class="gwt-TabBarRest-wrapper" style="vertical-align: bottom;"><div id="some_id" class="gwt-TabBarRest" style="white-space: normal; height: 100%;">&nbsp;</div></td>
```

Now use the following code snippet.

```
Button button = new Button();
....
....

RootPanel.get("some_id").add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    ButtonElement buttonEl = DOM.createButton().cast();
    buttonEl.setInnerHTML("MyButton01");
    Element el = DOM.getElementById("myButtonPlace");
    el.appendChild(buttonEl);
    DOM.sinkEvents(el, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
    DOM.sinkEvents(buttonEl, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
    DOM.setEventListener(buttonEl,
                         new EventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                                GWT.debugger();
                                switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
                                    case Event.ONCLICK: GWT.log("you clicked the button");
                                    break;
                                    case Event.ONMOUSEOVER: GWT.log("the mouse is over the button");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in JQuery with .html method wich allow you to set the content of an HTML element.

```
$("div.gwt-TabBarRest").html('<button type="button" class="gwt-Button helpButton"></button>');
```